# How can test MutableLiveData<>.observe when the data is changed?

Tags: android, junit, android-testing, robolectric, android-mvvm

I have the next code for test if the API is working with Login function:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class LoginTest {
    LoginRespository profileRepository = new LoginRespository(RuntimeEnvironment.application);

    @Test
    public void testLogin() {
        MutableLiveData<ApiResponse<LoginData>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        String email = "email@email.com";
        String password = "email@email.com";
        profileRepository.login(data, email, password);

    }
}
```

The data of the API return is saved into `data` and but I do not know how can put the observer here, because I need the context, and maybe that the `testLogin`, not finishes.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly, I can test with robolectric with the next code:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class DownloadProfileTest {
    LoginRespository profileRepository = new LoginRespository(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
    private ActivityController<LoginActivity> controller;
    private LoginActivity activity;

    private void createLoginActivityWithIntent() {
        activity = controller
                .create()
                .start()
                .get();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUtilsIsValidEmail() {
        MutableLiveData<ApiResponse<LoginData>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        String email = "email@email.com";
        String password = "email@email.com";
        profileRepository.login(data, email, password);
        createLoginActivityWithIntent();

        data.observe(activity, (@Nullable ApiResponse<LoginData> loginResponse) -> {
            assertTrue(loginResponse != null);
        });
    }
}
```